# setOnClickListener Error: No Idea Why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Android Development, and I can't for the life of me, figure out why this is giving me an error. The error is occurring on this line: 'bu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {'

I am following the Android Development Fundamental tutorials on Lynda.com; and my code is identical to that of the teachers; or so I think.

```
package com.lynda.lyndaproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity {

    Button bu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
            }               
        });
    }   
}
```

By the way, Eclipse doesn't seem to be allowing me to import anything; and I do believe importing 'android.view.View' should have imported everything necessary.

Comment: your import is wrong. you need to import View.OnClickListener, not Dialog.OnClickListener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to fix your import. You are using the wrong `OnClickListener`. Change the line

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

to

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Next, You need to move the line

```
Button bu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

To after the call to `setContentView(...)`. So your `onCreate` method would look like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    bu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

        }


    });
}
```

This is because `findViewById(...)` looks for a `View` in the current layout. Since this has not been set by `setContentView`, it will always return `null`.

Comment: I did that, and I had that previously. It doesn't resolve the errors.

Comment: @user3267022 see the edit. You need to fix your import

Comment: @user3267022 glad I could help. Don't for get to accept this, and get +2 reputation :)